# How to fix 'CGAL::Precondition_exception' when constructing Polygon_set_2

Tags: cgal

I'm using the CGAL library in a a Visual Studio project.
I'm trying to create a polygon_set_2 composed of polygons with holes.  I run into an exception when creating the polygon_set_2 even when just using simple polygons.

Typedefs:

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 CGALPoint;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> CGALInnerPolygon;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_set_2<K> CGALMultiPolygon;
```

Problem code:

```cpp
        CGALInnerPolygon cgalpoly;
        cgalpoly.push_back(CGALPoint(0, 0));
        cgalpoly.push_back(CGALPoint(1, 1));
        cgalpoly.push_back(CGALPoint(1, 0));

        CGALMultiPolygon multipolygon;
        multipolygon.insert(cgalpoly);
```

I get an exception on the insert call.  Output for the exception is:

Exception thrown at 0x75112CF2 in XXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CGAL::Precondition_exception at memory location 0x00191AF0

Comment: My guess is that the polygon should be counterclockwise. Try reversing the order of insertion of your points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a combination of two things.  First the polygon points much be counterclockwise as *sloriot* mentioned.  To fix for this in the general case the following code was added:

```cpp
if (cgalpoly.is_clockwise_oriented())
{
    cgalpoly.reverse_orientation();
}
```

Secondly, the the Polygon_set_2 must use an exact construction kernel:

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
```